# Access Recyclerview viewholder from activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm developing a music player app for android. When a song completes I send a broadcast and in an activity i want to change the play/pause icon in a row accordingly.

The activity  receives the broadcast of next song but I don't know how to update row from activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_now_playing);

        mStaggerGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.now_playing_songs_list);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mStaggerGridLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, mSongList)
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if(intent.getAction().equals(MusicService.SONG_FINISHED)) {
                    //WANT TO CHANGE ROW ICON HERE
                }
            }
        };
```

How do I access viewholder defined inside mAdapter in activity?

Comment: Make a public method in your ListAdapter class to handle this action, and call that method from onReceive() in the Activity.

Comment: most likely, you don't want to access the viewHolder. Instead, you want to modify one of the data entries in the adapter and then notify the adapter that the item has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change your model from your activity and then ask adapter to update the view. `Single responsibility` is one of the `oop` design principles. For example all song objects must have a `boolean` value name it `isPlaying`. When user is playing a song it must be set to `true`. then when you receive your `broadcast` you find that song from your list and set the `boolean` to `false` and then call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. in your `getView` method you just check that variable and set `UI` to say pause or play state.